# What is the "Pass by * &" for?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

What does it mean?  I understand the use of pass by reference is to pass in the reference so you can directly alter it without the need of a return, and pass by pointer is similar but with a slower runtime.  However, I do not understand what * & does.  For an example,

```
foo(int * & var) { }
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you go the "pass by pointer is similar but with a slower runtime" from. For all intents and purposes, the performance of passing an object by pointer or by reference are identical (and pass-by-reference is often implemented using pointers under the hood).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It passes a pointer by reference so that you can change what the pointer points to and have those changes reflected to the caller.

For example:

```
void notByReference(int *p) {
    p = nullptr;
}

void byReference(int *&p) {
    p = nullptr;
}

int main() {
    int *i = new int;
    notByReference(i); //i is not changed since a copy of the pointer was passed
    byReference(i); //i itself is changed, leaking memory
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see, so notByReference is like passing by value for a pointer.

Comment: @Goyatuzo, Yes, it passes the pointer by value, creating a copy. The copy points to the same thing, so whatever its pointing to can be ultimately changed, but the pointer itself is different, so modifying it to point elsewhere only takes effect on the copy.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the quick and comprehensive reply!

Answer (score 2):

This allows you to pass a pointer by reference. Which gives the function the opportunity to modify the pointer and have that modification seen by the caller.

You don't need to stop there. You can pass by reference a pointer to pointer to int, for example.

```
void foo(int** &var)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that type qualifiers like `&` and `*` are independent of each other. When you see `some_type&` it simply means "reference to `sometype`", which in turn means that the function sees the caller's version of the argument and can modify it. When `sometype` is a pointer it just means that the type of the caller's version of the argument is a pointer, and the function can modify that pointer.